# Saving certain generated html table into a session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to google around but couldn't really find an answer.

So.. basically I have a reapeater which prints out all of database rows.
You can then click on add to add it to another table and here I would like to save the table somehow as a session so it won't reset everytime I refresh my page.

The html strcuture of the 2nd table after you add items looks like that

```
<table id="SECOND">
  <tr>
     <td>Content</td>
     <td>Content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Content2</td>
     <td>Content2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then I would like to click on button or something and save this table into a session but honestly I have no idea how to do that :C

@Forgot to add, I add rows from first to second via jquery.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you want to achieve? In which cases are you reloading the page so need to keep table2 state? Is there any event when you persist table2 state so don't need to retain it anymore?. Session data is stored in cookie, so it wouldn't be a good place to store your entire table, so it would be great to have more details to post a good answer

Comment: @tede24 Sure, sorry for not providing enough details. As I stated above, with reapeter I print out all rows from DB inside of a table, then If you click on +(add) which is placed in each row you can add it to #SECOND table from the #FIRST via jquery. There is lot of items inside, about hundred. So, if user somehowly refresh the page or will switch pages and go back to the one with table, he or she will have to put items again to #SECOND from #FIRST. And this is something I want to prevent by storing/saving it somehow.

Comment: Ok but when you finish moving from t1 to t2? Is theme any kind of "save" is something when table 2 get updated?

Comment: Saving the table itself is probably not a good idea. Instead, save the data in the table. You can place that in HTML5 localStorage.

Comment: @tede24 No, the t2 just shows up above the t1 with chosen items. Also the item from t1 is removed and added to t2 but when you refresh page, all is returning to state where you just print out a DB rows and being able to add items to t2. That's why I'm looking for some way to save it.

Comment: @mason Not sure how could I do it. Never dont it before ;<

Comment: Then that means you should do some research and look at what localStorage is and how you would use it.

Comment: Could you specify how long should this table2 data live? When should it be discarded? And please, for the completeness of your question, add this and previous details to question body

Comment: @tede24 Sorry for answering so late but had to go somewhere... Well, 20minutes? It doesn't have to be pernament.

Comment: Is your user identified or is anonymous?

Comment: @tede24 Identified, logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7(v=vs.100).aspx) you have a MSDN document about options to store state (disregard ViewState if you are not in WebForms).

Anyway, I wouldn't go for session, as you are storing a lot of info (you mention hundreds of rows). I wouldn't go for any solution based roundtrips at all as you will be transmitting lot of data on every page load.

So I think you have two options:

1. Use any kind of HTML local storage solution. This is not C# nor backend, but just client technology. Pros: data will live in client, you will never transmit it, save, read, nothing. Cons: depending on which local storage strategy you choose, you will have to deal with browser compatibility and maybe some older browsers won't work. You could go for [JQuery LocalStorage](https://plugins.jquery.com/storageapi/), or if you don't want to use any library then research for HTML5 Local Storage.
2. As your user is identified, you can store this in database, and retrieve it whenever you need it. Pros: it will work with any browser, data will live as long as you want, even the data could be available in any other workstation for this user (depending on your needs). Cons: as far as you are already using database in your application, I can't see cons...

I would choose option number 2, I use this strategy for Shopping Cart for example. But it depends on you.

Comment: Can I ask how could I store it with use of your 2nd option? Like additional table for it? And how would all put all those items in there ;o?

Comment: You are asking for a full path to persist data in database? Please search for any CRUD example in Google. There are plenty of examples/options out there, maybe asp.net/mvc page for tutorials

Comment: Thanks for help, I'll surely lecture it :)